# Selenium com plugin Maven não funciona os testes

Tags: java, spring, testes, junit

- Implementação para funcionar um conjunto de testes JUnit e testNG,
- Quando executado pelo plugin do eclipse, funciona.
- Pelo maven não, o comportamento dos testes testNG, são alterados,
- Parece que que não termina direito as sessões http,
- Cria uma sessão http, quando (login logout)

Os principais lib do pom, tentei configurar conforme orientações da apache:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
    </plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                    <name>junit</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
```

Abaixo o resultado dos testes executados pelo plugin do Eclipse:

```
===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

- O problema dos testes é que individuais eles funcionam,
- Pegando o conjunto de classes(4) do testNG rondando pelo plugin do Eclipse, funciona,
- Rondando o conjunto de testes JUnit (44) funciona,
- Quando entra **os dois junto ai da erro** nas sessões http (criados no teste NG).

Parece que ele esta tentando fazer login e antes mesmo de terminar o logout, começa a outra classe, fazendo login, mas ainda nem terminou de fazer logout.. ai desse ponto em diante da erro em todas as classes.

Resumo da login logout:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    baseUrl = SysCodeTest.URL_PATH_TEST;
    this.login();

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    this.logout();
}
```

Alguém já passou por isso, consegue apontar algum problema de configuração?
abaixo log erro:

```
Failed tests: 
SysNGSeleniumDriverChromeTest.setUp:18 » Timeout timeout: cannot determine loa...
com.sys.mod.login.SysGroupControllerTest.(com.sys.mod.login.SysGroupControllerTest)
Run 1: SysGroupControllerTest.setUp:29->SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.login:49 » NoSuchElement
Run 2: PASS

com.sys.mod.login.SysPaperControllerTest.(com.sys.mod.login.SysPaperControllerTest)
Run 1: PASS
Run 2: PASS
Run 3: SysPaperControllerTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->changePaper:101 » NoSuchElement
Run 4: SysPaperControllerTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->removePaper:130 » NoSuchElement
Run 5: SysPaperControllerTest>SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.tearDown:86->SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.logout:60 » NoSuchElement

com.sys.mod.login.SysUserControllerTest.(com.sys.mod.login.SysUserControllerTest)
Run 1: SysUserControllerTest.setUp:29->SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.login:49 » NoSuchElement
Run 2: PASS
Run 3: SysUserControllerTest>SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.tearDown:86->SysNGSeleniumDriverChrome.logout:60 » NoSuchElement
```

Comment: `NoSuchElement` acontece quandop o Selenium não encontra o componente baseado no id informado. Tem certeza que o componente está com id correto?

Comment: Que provavelmente ocorre dentro do `logout()`...

Comment: Sim tenho, pois se executo, classe por classe, funciona, porém se executo todos os testes, inclusive o JUnit, ai ele se perde

Comment: Ele não encontra o id, porque a tela que deveria estar para o teste, foi mudado por outro agente parece.